# Printing order in C

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

```
int x=10;
printf("%d %d %d\n",x,++x,x++);
printf("%d %d %d",x,x+20,x+30);
```

It is printing output as

```
12 12 10
12 32 42
```

**Why the order in first printf is in reverse order and why not in second printf statement?**
i found in a book that C uses reverse printing order.

Comment: or... [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points), and likely many others.

Comment: During evaluation, first it will take all the values starting from right into the stack. If the variable has any post/pre increment, it evaluates and stores the value. Else, it stores as a variable in the stack and takes the final value of the var. right most x++ - 10, because its post inc updates x as 11. for ++i - 12, pre inc and updates x as 12 for x as it is in the stack. Final output will be 12 12 10 which is the order of retrieving from stack.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has **undefined behavior** ("UB"). Thus, anything can happen.

Specifically, the rule violated is that one must not read and write the same variable without sequence-point except to determine the value to write.

Comment: As comment length is limited i have rephrased the statement as printf("%d %d %d %d",i,++i, i++,i); with i=1 During evaluation, first it will take all the values starting from right into the stack. If the variable has any post/pre increment, it evaluates and stores the value. Else, it stores as a variable in the stack and takes the final value of the var. right most i - i in to the stack, for i++ - 1 because its post inc updates i as 2. for ++i - 3, pre inc and updates i as 3 for i as it is in the stack. for var as i in stack takes final value of i as 3. Final output will be 3 3 1 3

Comment: @Dinesh: That does not follow from the standard...

Comment: printf follows the rule which i specified above. there is not such sperate rule for the varibales changed and unchanged.

Comment: @Dinesh: Did you ever read the standard, or the other posts linked above?