# How exactly is the program running?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C and I came across a code which went like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k=35;
    printf("%d %d %d",k==35,k=50,k>40);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to find the output without writing the code in my computer and 'actually' running it first. So here's how I figured out what the output might be:

In the precedence table, among assignment (`==`), equality (`=`) and greater than (`>`) operators, the greater than operator will be implemented first. So, initially, `k=35` and thus `k>40` is false (the integer thus will be `0`). Next up is the equality operator (`==`). Now, `k==35` is true initially. So this will return an integer `1`. Finally, the assignment operator (`=`) will do its job, set the value of k to `50`(and ultimately, returning `50`) and the program will exit. Thus, based on this logic, I 'guessed' that final output will be like:

```
1 50 0
```

Now I ran the code in my IDE (I'm coming to my IDE a bit later) and the result it gave was:

```
0 50 0
```

So, my confusion is, in which order are the operators being implemented?

Any help or hints are very much welcome.

**NOTE:** I noticed a bit closer and found that the only way possible is: First the `>` operator does its job, then the `=` operator and finally, the `==` operator.

I changed my `printf` line a bit and wrote:

```
printf("%d %d %d",k==35,k>40,k=50);
```

Here, I found that the output was:

```
0 1 50
```

which, again was not according to what I 'guessed' initially with my logic.

I tried all the possible ordering of the syntax inside the `printf()` function. After looking at all those outputs, I doubt: Is the program being implemented in a `right-to-left` order here irrespective of the ordering in the precedence table?

**NOTE:** Regarding my IDE, I use Dev C++ 5.11. I use it as our instructor has advised us to use it for our course. As this IDE is not so much well-received among many others, I tried an online compiler, but the results are the same.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069248/printing-order-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is *undefined* - the result is not guaranteed to be predictable or repeatable.

First, precedence only controls which operators are grouped with which operands - it does not control the order in which expressions are evaluated.

Second, the order in which function arguments are evaluated is *unspecified* - they can be evaluated right-to-left, left-to-right, or any other order<sup>1</sup>.

Finally, you are updating `k` (`k = 50`) and attempting to use it in a value computation (`k == 35`, `k > 40`) without an intervening sequence point, which is explicitly called out by the language definition as undefined behavior.

So the result can literally be *anything*, even what you expect it to be.  You can’t rely on it to be consistent or predictable.

---

1. This is not the same as the order in which they are passed to the function.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now. I got this code chunk from a book which asked what would be its output. I initially thought that it was undefined but I couldn't believe that it'll be in a question.

Comment: In addition to right-to-left, left-to-right, or “any other order,” argument evaluation may be interleaved, such as evaluating some subexpressions of one argument before  subexpressions of another argument in arbitrary orders and combinations. That includes a possibility that writing individual bytes to `k` in `k=50` may be interleaved with uses of the value of `k`, which is why the overall behavior is undefined.

Comment: @DebarthaPaul: Unfortunately, there are a lot of bad C textbooks and tutorials, written by people who don’t understand the language as well as they think they do.  This is a common misconception in many of them.

Answer (score 0):

> printf("%d %d %d",k==35,k=50,k>40);

This is undefined behavior.
The order of evaluation of the arguments is simply unspecified.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3575375/13912132) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) for further explanation.

> Order of evaluation of the operands of any C operator, including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call expression, and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within any expression is unspecified[...]. The compiler will evaluate them in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.